# What does "Round the corner comes the postman" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

*Round the corner* means *nearby*. However, I have difficulty with understanding the sentence "Round the corner comes the postman". Inversion has happened.

Comment: We would not use *round the corner* to mean some thing is *nearby* if the thing was not *around the corner*.

Comment: @pazzo , seems [the free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/around+the+corner) disagrees: "2. Nearby, a short distance away"

Comment: Well @Stephie we could always take a poll of native speakers.

Comment: @Juya This is similar to *Here comes the bride*.

Answer (score 2):

Kudos for recognizing that "(a)round the corner" can mean "nearby".
But sometimes things are to be read without second meaning: The postman simply walks around the corner.

"Round the corner" is not figuratively (=nearby) but quite literally used *in this example*. It follows the same pattern as

> He walks "down the stairs" or "through the door".

If you are unsure which meaning is correct, you will have to check the context.

Comment: Then what does "The postman comes around the corner" mean?

Comment: @Juya: like in [this picture](http://www.corbisimages.com/stock-photo/rights-managed/42-23727527/multiple-exposure-shot-of-businessman-walking-around), only with a postman instead of a businessman. If without the inversion, your sentence would read: "The postman comes around the corner."

Comment: thx a million! so *come* here means *walk* :)

Comment: I think that will be great if you add the photo to your answer.

Comment: @Juya In fact, I won't - I wouldn't want to mess around with copyrights.

Comment: @Juya , comes = walks towards you.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently from a book called *Primary Education Volume 11*  published in 1903 with lesson plans for elementary school children.  A section on suggestions for February describes children making Valentine's Day cards for their classmates, which missives they seal in envelopes and give to a designated classmate to deliver, while they all sing

```
Round the corner comes the postman,
Whistling on his merry way,
While his happy smile is telling
He has jolly times today.
```

The tune is that of the popular song "Clementine."  The first line means "The postman comes around the corner," but the word "round" is chosen over "around" and the ordinary Subject-Verb order ("the postman comes") is reversed to Verb-Subject ("comes the postman") to fit the meter.

Comment: then what does "The postman comes around the corner" mean?